# query to select columns from a row in which another column has certain value only SQL

Tags: sql

Consider the following table

```
id   attribute
1     a
1     a
1     b
2     a
2     a
3     c
4     a
```

I want to select the ids that have attribute of 'a' only, ie 2 and 4.
Cant select 1 because 1 has 'a' and 'b', cant select 3 because it has 'c' only. We select 2 and 4 because it has 'a' value only.

Comment: I have removed the tag spam here; please don't do it. Just tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT id
FROM   YourTable
GROUP  BY id
HAVING MAX(attribute) = 'a' AND MIN(attribute) = 'a'
       AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(attribute)
```

the

```
COUNT(*) = COUNT(attribute)
```

is to discard any id that have `NULL` attribute as well as `a`. Remove this if that is not the semantics you want or the column is not nullable anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please test this:

```
SELECT id
FROM attribute
GROUP BY id
HAVING 
COUNT(DISTINCT attribute) = 1 AND MIN(attribute)= 'a';
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT attribute)` is generally a less performant aggregate than other solutions because it often requires some additional work to identify the distinct attributes to be counted.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes; but in this case , difference is so minimal. (0.00073 VS 0.00077)  worth ignoring it ?

Comment: In what case? You seem to be doing perf testing using an RDBMS, data, and table structure none of which were given in the question (certainly the example data in the question won't be the actual production data that the query is needed for)

Comment: we are testing on the same database with same table structure, and I am saying the difference is minimal; but I wonder what if data grows so much ? will the difference be ignorable then ? maybe No.

Comment: table structure also includes indexes. For example in SQL Server world if there was an index on `id INCLUDE (attribute)` then this could just be scanned in order of id and fed into a stream aggregate where the "simple" aggregates can be calculated easily by just looking at the stream. Including `COUNT(DISTINCT attribute)` would probably end up with a sort to get the rows into `id, attribute` order first. But if there was already an index on `id, attribute` this sort wouldn't be needed. So that aggregation either requires more work or more demanding pre-requisites to avoid it.

Comment: @Martin we will discuss here broadly about optimization? yes, you are right; but  what I am trying to say here is that under the same conditions, difference is minimal. I respect your knowledge about optimization; but the issue here is that we can safely accept this solution because of ignorable difference.

Comment: It would not be ignorable if you were in the situation where the database engine was sorting millions of rows unnecessarily. It just seems unnecessary to use a potentially problematic construct when safer ones exist

Comment: Probably yes; but I would test and give my decision accordingly.

Comment: This seems to work but I don't understand how. What is the MIN(attribute)='a' doing?

Comment: SQL orders characters by their ascii codes. attribute column contains 3 characters (a, b, c). You can run this statement : SELECT ascii('a'),ascii('b'),ascii('c')             The result. 'a' = 97, 'b' = 98, 'c' = 99. Minimum is 'a'.

Comment: @OzanSen Then wouldn't the above mentioned query also return rows with containing attribute value of 'b' or other attribute greater than 'a'. How does it return rows containing attribute column value of 'a' only ?

Comment: @yojanshakya It returns only 'a' because of MIN(attribute). If It were the MAX(attribute) then It would return 'c'. Logic is not complex here. Just think of it as each character having an ascii code.